# How to centering span

Tags: html, css, center

How to centering that download button? I tested many times but it's wrong codes.

```css
.col {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.download {
  width: auto;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 17px 37px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <span class="download">Download</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `float:left;` from `.download` (because it forces the element to be floated to the left).
2. Give `display:inline-block;` (It acts like `inline` element, it means you can center it by giving `text-align:center;` to its parent.)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/zqs2kkt8/3/)

```css
.col {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.download {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 17px 37px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `text-align: center;` to `.col` and replace `float:left` with `display:inline-block;` in the button element. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqs2kkt8/4/)